# How do I make this to a php string and echo it into <select>?

Tags: php, html

This makes me crazy I cant get it to work.

This is what ive done:

```
$v = "<?php if($test== 'lala' || $test== 'kaka'){echo selected='selected';}?>";
$b = "<?php if($test== 'tada' || $test== 'sada'){echo selected='selected';}?>";

<select>
      <option <?php echo $v; ?> value="lala">lala</option>
        <option  <?php echo $b; ?> value="tada">tada</option>
</select>
```

in the dropdown this gives me: **value="tada">tada** and it should only be **tada**

Comment: it won't be interpreted, just assign the variable normally, then echo the result: `$v = ($test== 'lala' || $okkon == 'kaka') ? 'selected' : '';` ternary example

Comment: return to basic php syntax, then get fancy once you understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are messed up.

Change:

```
    $v = "<?php if($test== 'lala' || $test== 'kaka'){echo selected='selected';}?>";
$b = "<?php if($test== 'tada' || $test== 'sada'){echo selected='selected';}?>";
```

To:

```
<option <?php if($test== 'lala' || $test== 'kaka'){echo 'selected=selected';}?> value="lala">lala</option>
<option  <?php if($test== 'tada' || $test== 'sada'){echo 'selected=selected';} ?> value="tada">tada</option>
```